Unable to debug and see logs of my Class-based Durable Functions
I've created a new FunctionApp (.net 8 Isolated) to run a Orchestration workflow, so after test the template generated it worked fine, I was able to debug the orchestrator function, the activity function and see their respective logs.
But after change my Orchestrator and Activity to be Class-based, I don't see any error happening during the execution, and I see host logs saying that the Orchestratior started and finished, successfully, but I don't any log from my logInformation that worked before and I don't see any evidency that my ActivityTrigger run.
[DurableTask(nameof(MyActivity))]
public class MyActivity : TaskActivity<string, string>
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public MyActivity(ILogger<MyActivity> logger) // activities have access to DI.
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async override Task<string> RunAsync(TaskActivityContext context, string input)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Inside Activity");
        return "it's working";        
    }
}

[DurableTask(nameof(MyOrchestration))]
public class MyOrchestration : TaskOrchestrator<string, string>
{
    public async override Task<string> RunAsync(TaskOrchestrationContext context, string input)
    {
        ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger<MyOrchestration>(); // orchestrations do NOT have access to DI.

        // An extension method was generated for directly invoking "MyActivity".
        return await context.CallMyActivityAsync(input);
    }
}

I've tried the Function-Based rollback and worked fine, changing only the ActivityTrigger to Class-based, it does not enter when I'm debugging, neither I see any logs, but there is no error during the execution.

Can you provide complete code?


but I don't any log from my logInformation that worked before and I don't see any evidency that my ActivityTrigger run.

You do not need to use dependency injection, you can log using below code:
Program.cs:
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
    
    var rith = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
            services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    
        })
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
    
        .Build();
    
    rith.Run();

Function.cs:
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
    using Microsoft.DurableTask;
    using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    
    namespace FunctionApp
    {
        public static class Function1
        {
            [Function("Function1_Rith_HttpStart")]
            public static async Task<HttpResponseData> Rith_HttpStart(
                [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData ri,
                [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient rcl,
                FunctionContext rct)
            {
                ILogger ri_lg = rct.GetLogger("Function1_Rith_HttpStart");
                string inid = await rcl.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(nameof(Rith_Orchestrator));
                ri_lg.LogInformation("SHello Rithwik Bojja,  Orchestrator ID = '{instanceId}'.", inid);
                return await rcl.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(ri, inid);
            }
        }
        public class Rith_Orchestrator
        {
            private readonly ILogger<Rith_Orchestrator> ri_log;
    
            public Rith_Orchestrator(ILogger<Rith_Orchestrator> lg)
            {
                ri_log = lg;
            }
    
            [Function("Rith_Orchestrator")]
            public async Task<string> RunAsync([OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext ricxt)
            {
                ri_log.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Logging from Orchestrator");
                return await ricxt.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(Rith_Test_Activity), "Rithwik_Bojja");
            }
        }
        public class Rith_Test_Activity
        {
            private readonly ILogger<Rith_Test_Activity> ri_lger;
    
            public Rith_Test_Activity(ILogger<Rith_Test_Activity> lg)
            {
                ri_lger = lg;
            }
    
            [Function("Rith_Test_Activity")]
            public async Task<string> RunAsync([ActivityTrigger] string ri)
            {
                ri_lger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja, inside activity and the name is {ri}.", ri);
                return await Task.FromResult($" Activity is {ri}!");
            }
        }
    }

Output:




I'm trying to use Class-based for my Orchestrator and Activity, that is what is causing my problem, is there and the main problem is that I can't debug it when it is designed as Class-based =(
